# append specieal charecters in payload tag in Mule ESB

Tags: mule

i want payload value like below in `<http:outbound-endpoint>`:

```
<set-variable variableName="url" value="#[json:url]" doc:name="Variable"></set-variable>
<set-variable variableName="payload" value="#[json:param]" doc:name="Variable"></set-variable>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://admin:admin@#[url.substring(7)]" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" password="admin" user="admin">
    <set-payload value="action=start&params={input:#[payload]}&createTask=false&parts=all"/>
</http:outbound-endpoint>
```

but it is giving error.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the error by replacing `&` with `&amp;`

However, that is not your only problem.

1. `payload` is a reserved variable to hold the current payload. You can not use `set-variable` with `variableName="payload"`, your setting will just be ignored when you call `#[payload]` later.
2. Your POST data would be something like `action=start&params={input:yourdata}&createTask=false&parts=all`. This is some kind of hybrid of JSON and HTTP GET syntax, and I doubt that this is what you are trying to achieve. If you want to send a POST request in key=val format, set a payload of type Map. If you want to send the request as JSON, set a payload with a JSON String, you have the `object-to-json-transformer` to help in Mule. If you want to have parameters in the URL, put them in the URL. But you can not mix these different syntaxes.